# xmlhttprequest load specific div from an external HTML

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, bootstrap-modal

I am using xhlhttprequest to load an external html file.  However I am trying to figure out how to load only a speicific DIV from that html file.

My external page is `helpFile.html`- it has dozens header `<DIV>`s, an each header DIV is a specific help section.  On different pages, I want to be able load a specific section?  How could I do this?  As an example, on the `dashboard.html` page is a help `?` icon, that when the user clicks on it, it will load just the `helpFile.html#dashboard` section out of the main helpFile.html page - the content would be loaded into a bootstrap modal.

Here is my code to retrieve the entire page, but how can I just retrieve the needed section.

```
<script>
    var request;

    function sendInfo() {

        var url = "helpFile.html";

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }     else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
            request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        try {
            request.onreadystatechange = getInfo;
            request.open("GET", url, true);
            request.send();
        } catch (e) {
            alert("Unable to connect to server");
        }
    }

    function getInfo() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
            var val = request.responseText;
            document.getElementById('helpModal').innerHTML = val;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use DOMParser and look for the element

```
if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
  var parser = new DOMParser();
  var doc = parser.parseFromString(request.responseText;, "text/html");
  var dashboardElement = doc.querySelector("#dashboard");
  document.getElementById('helpModal').innerHTML = dashboardElement.innerHTML;
}
```

Comment: that looks great, going to try it out tonight.